# SQL Reporting Services 2005 - Printing in FireFox

Tags: firefox, reporting-services, printing

Printing button is not shown in the report toolbar when they are opened in FireFox.

Is there any solution for print button not showing in FireFox ?
Can it be enabled or there is no workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your only option here is to export to pdf or another format and then print.

The print button on the toolbar is an activex control, which is not and probably will not be supported in firefox.

Comment: This is not an option for the client. I will have to make regular HTML page and print this :(